# ASIHTTPRequest stops downloading when request:willRedirectToUrl: is implemented

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, url, asihttprequest

As soon as I add the `request:willRedirectToUrl:` method in the delegate the request stops downloading from the redirected url, if I don't implement the method it continues to download the file from the new url. Its driving me crazy, why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement the delegate willRedirectToUrl, the delegate gets full control of what will happen on a redirection, so it needs to take the necessary action - from the .h:

```
// Called on the delegate (if implemented) when the request receives a Location header and shouldRedirect is YES
// The delegate can then change the url if needed, and can restart the request by calling [request redirectToURL:], or simply cancel it
```

So you just need to call:

```
// Can be called by delegates from inside their willRedirectSelector implementations to restart the request with a new url
- (void)redirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL;
```

passing the newURL.